# A MongoDB cluster spread over geographically distant locations with high local availability demands

Tags: mongodb

I am wondering if there is any way to set up a MongoDB cluster with nodes spread across several physical locations where a disconnected node may keep working independently (i.e perform both read and write operations locally) of the cluster and later re-sync(as much as data conflicts may permit) with the cluster when the connection is re-established.

Thanks.

Comment: Might be a better fit on http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There were only 200 questions tagged with mongodb over there so I assumed it wasn't actually the right place to ask :)

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions and this really is far more infrastructure. (That being said, MongoDB doesn't have MVCC support, so I'm not sure how a disconnected system would reconnect and properly work). Have you read up on http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-geographically-distributed-replica-set/